# Reading 2 files from S3 bucket, doing transformations then writing the result to another target file in the same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have PySpark script that does some dataframe transformations. I would like to place it in AWS Glue where I read from 2 files in S3 Bucket, run the job/script and write the result to another file in the same bucket. I'm new to AWS so I let Glue create the line of code needed to read from the source and specify the target. However the job keeps failing. I am certain the issue isn't with the script as it runs perfectly locally. Here is what it looks like:

```
 <datasource1> = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "trial-db", table_name = "tbl1_csv", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

 <datsource2> = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "trial-db", table_name = "data_txt", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

 #PySpark Transformation script goes here...

 <datatarget> = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = <frame>, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path":"s3://demo-trial-data/write"}, format = "csv", format_options = <format_options>, transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
```

Comment: can you check the cloud watch logs, and print the error message? For cloudwatch logs, select your job, and in the job history, click on the errorlogs.

Comment: The error I am getting is that entity is not found, but I do have a db with 2 tables in it.

Comment: How are the source tables created and the tables and Glue code is in same region? Is it possible for you to post the full error trace?